# Why can two containers in host network namespace both bind to the same port?

Tags: networking, docker, port, container

I was working with Docker containers with `--network host` set and realized, that if I bind to a port in one container I can still start a second one which binds on the same port without any error message.
`netstat` will then show the PID from the second container as listening instead of the PID of the first one.

Steps to reproduce:

```
[root@test]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="9.2 (Plow)"
...
[root@test]# docker --version
Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc
```

```
[root@test]# docker run -d --rm --network host --name container01 debian nc -l -p 80
7bc250856c7ddde57eb48f57ba800391577c728ec856da24bf80a9df8e766c84

[root@test]# netstat -tulpen | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          10435480   2162661/nc

[root@test]# docker run -d --rm --network host --name container02 debian nc -l -p 80
10897d7dea695446db48bff9d3b338554a7cd0535f30625f06b6e5f959bf8df2

[root@test]# netstat -tulpen | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          10436217   2162708/nc

[root@test]# ps auxf
root     2162640  0.0  0.5 720496 10608 ?        Sl   11:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 7bc250856c7ddde57eb48f57ba800391
root     2162661  0.0  0.0   3200  1116 ?        Ss   11:03   0:00  \_ nc -l -p 80
root     2162686  0.0  0.5 720496 10028 ?        Sl   11:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 10897d7dea695446db48bff9d3b33855
root     2162708  0.0  0.0   3200  1060 ?        Ss   11:03   0:00  \_ nc -l -p 80
```

An existing connections to the first container keeps working even after the second is started. All new connections will go to the second.

Of course binding to the same port directly on the host does not work and neither can't the container bind to a port on which the host is already listing.

So my question is: What exactly is different for the containers so that they can overtake a already existing port binding?

Comment: Sometimes when you connect to a port, the connection is immediately closed and a new connection is started with a different port to free the listening port. Could this be happening here?

Comment: No I can use connections to both containers simultaniously. Of course a TCP connection to the first container can only be established before the second takes over.

Comment: well, it makes sense that both containers have their own interfaces, so yes they can establish their own set of ports and have no means to coordinate how ports are allocated amongst themselves as a group. So there is nothing to stop them from both running services on the same port. the issue you have is in reaching that port, and the hosts inability to distinguish which endpoint you want.

Comment: As stated, the are both running in the hosts network namespace. They don't have their on interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly the same way you can have multiple sessions on a single port port from the same client. Connections use a [socket pair](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPPortsConnectionsandConnectionIdentification.htm) (which includes a unique client-side ephemeral port) to identify themselves. The host uses these unique pairs to send traffic to the correct process id - sometimes even after the host port itself has been bound by a different process. They should stay active until the host closes the port, ends those sessions, ends that process id, etc.

There are some limitations on how software can allow re-binding to ports based on the operating system and available options. I found some good details on that and the binding process (in linux) in the answers here: [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)